# How would I limit the amount of items in a tableview and automatically load more?

Tags: swift, uitableview, reload

again real quick would like to say thanks to all those who helped me out.

The last thing that I'm dealing with is as follows.

I have a search functionality in my application and it looks through parse for a keyword and matches accordingly. It works fine now, but as the list gets bigger, I'm assuming the load times might be a little much. It instantly shows roughly 200 text results and I'm wondering if it'll crash or lag when showing 2,000.

The following is the important parts of my search class.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    //myCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "goodbg"))

    //myCell.contentView.backgroundColor =  UIImage(named: "nobg")
    if myCell.backgroundView == nil {
        myCell.backgroundView = UIImageView(frame: myCell.contentView.bounds)
        myCell.backgroundView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
        myCell.backgroundView?.clipsToBounds = true
        myCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }
    //myCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    let backgroundImageView = myCell.backgroundView as! UIImageView
    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nobg")
    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]
    myCell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-bold", size: 17)
    myCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 126.0/255, green: 126.0/255, blue: 126.0/255, alpha: 1)
    myCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    myCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    return myCell
}


func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)
{

    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    var textSearchQuery = PFQuery(className: "Red")

    textSearchQuery.whereKey("text", containsString: searchBar.text)


    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([textSearchQuery])

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
        {
            (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil
            {
                //var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.self)
                //let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                //myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                //self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }

            if let objects = results as? [PFObject]
            {

                self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                for object in objects
                {
                    let searchText = object.objectForKey("text") as! String
                    self.searchResults.append(searchText)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                        self.myTable.reloadData()
                        self.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

How would I make it so maybe 100 items are loaded first and subsequent items are loaded once the user is near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be able to query in ranges. Then, combine the count of items in `self.searchResults` with `tableView(_: , willDisplayCell, forRowAtIndexPath:)`. That is, as the row gets to `self.searchResults.count` have the cell show as "Loading ..." and meanwhile trigger query in the next range.

Roughly speaking, in `willDisplayCell:` check

```
if notAlreadyFetching && self.searchResults.count == indexPath.row {
    // Fetch next range of 'searchResults'
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` have the last table cell be some kind of a loader (until your model gets updated and triggers a callback):

```
if self.searchResults.count == indexPath.row {
    // Return a loader cell
}
```

Comment: @JamesChen, I've elaborated further. If you've exhausted your model, you go and fetch more data. In meantime, you give the user some loading-feedback.